# Align function not counting equations correctly when referencing them

Tags: numbering, align, ref

When I use the `\begin{align}\end{align}` method to line up a group of related equations, the equation number next to the equation is counted correctly, but when I reference the equation using `\ref{eq:equationlabel}` or `\eqref{eq:equationlabel}`, it is off by a number or I end up with two question marks (??). I used the `\begin{equation}\end{equation}` method of creating equations, and the numbering works as it should.

I am using TeXstudio to compile the code below. The image below the code is what was generated. Has anyone ran into this problem? If so, how did they fix it?

```
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{{ - b \pm \sqrt {b^2 - 4ac} }}{{2a}}\\
\label{eq:quadratic_x_xb}
a &= 1+ \frac{\sec^2(\eta)}{3}\\
\label{eq:quadratic_a_xb}
b &= \frac{-2 \tan(\eta)\left\lVert \bf{v} \right\rVert}{{1-\Omega^2}}\\
\label{eq:quadratic_b_xb}
c &= \frac{\left\lVert \bf{v} \right\rVert ^2} 
{2}.\label{eq:quadratic_c_xb}\\
\end{align}

Example referencing equations (\ref{eq:quadratic_x_xb})-        
\eqref{eq:quadratic_c_xb}. The correct numbering should be (13)-(16).
```

[image: Snapshot of document snippet generated by the code above. The numbering in the referencing is not consistent with the actual equation number.]

Comment: You have not labeled the first rqn it needs to be before the \\

Answer (score 3):

You have

```
x &= \frac{{ - b \pm \sqrt {b^2 - 4ac} }}{{2a}}\\
\label{eq:quadratic_x_xb}
```

so the first equation (between `\begin{align}` and the first `\\`) has no `\label` .

You intended

```
x &= \frac{{ - b \pm \sqrt {b^2 - 4ac} }}{{2a}}\label{eq:quadratic_x_xb}\\
```

Comment: Thank you. You were right, my first equation did not have a label, but I also had to move all of the other equation labels up a layer: i.e.
'a &= 1+ \frac{\sec^2(\eta)}{3}\label{eq:quadratic_a_xb}\\', 'b &= \frac{-2 \tan(\eta)\left\lVert \bf{v} \right\rVert}{{1-\Omega^2}}\label{eq:quadratic_b_xb}\\', etc.

Comment: @DanielGonzalez yes of course and remove the spurious `\notag` arrangement at at the end

Comment: @DanielGonzalez unrelated but don't use `\bf` in any latex document written after 1993, it is not defined by default, but when it is defined for compatibility the syntax is `{\bf x}` not `\bf{x}` (also whu have you double braced the fraction arguments, `\frav{{..}}{{..}}` ?

Comment: That is a good and funny point about `\bf`. I will make sure not to use it anymore. That double curly bracket is probably a remnant of some operator I had outside of that first inner curly bracket.

Do I not need the `\notag` comment? I'm thinking I may have needed it because I was labeling the wrong lines, right?

Comment: I removed the `\notag` line and it worked! I edited my full answer to this question below.

Comment: @DanielGonzalez yes your final \lable was generating a spurious empty final equation, `\notag` removed the number (but would still have left bad spacing)

Answer (score 0):

@DavidCarlisle mentioned that I did not label my first equation. He was correct, but I also had to change all of the other lines to make the code compile. Below is the final code with a snapshot of the result:

```
\begin{align}
x &= \frac{{ - b \pm \sqrt {b^2 - 4ac} }}{{2a}}\label{eq:quadratic_x_xb}\\
a &= 1+ \frac{\sec^2(\eta)}{3}\label{eq:quadratic_a_xb}\\
b &= \frac{-2 \tan(\eta)\left\lVert \bf{v} \right\rVert}{{1-        
\Omega^2}}\label{eq:quadratic_b_xb}\\
c &= \frac{\left\lVert \bf{v} \right\rVert ^2}{2}. \label{eq:quadratic_c_xb}%\\
%\notag % prevents numbering of this line
\end{align}

Example referencing equations (\ref{eq:quadratic_x_xb})-\eqref{eq:quadratic_c_xb}. 
The correct numbering should be (15)-(18). It worked!
```

[image: Snapshot of code doing what I wanted.]

Comment: sorry I only mentioned the first explicitly but I assumed that it was clear the same applied to all of them (if you had provided a test document I would have provided a tested full answer)